# Samsung SSD and Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-10

I have ordered a Samsung 850 pro 512gb SSD, after searching online I have read a lot of trouble with Windows 10. I would like help with a trouble free install process. The way I have it planned is to:

1. Initialize & Format
2. Use easeus to clone the drive (I have an enclosure sata to usb cable will this suffice?)
3. Swap drives (My current drive is a 256gb Adata SSD).

The Samsung Software can be installed when it is compatible with Windows 10. Any guidance and/or direction with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recently successfully upgraded an ASUS laptop with Windows 10 Pro from an 1 TB HDD to the Samsung 850 Pro 2 TB SSH.

I did this entirely using tools already built into Windows.

My technique was:

1. Run Windows Image backup to external 2 TB USB 3 drive
2. Create the Repair CD (it offers to do that after the image backup finishes).
3. Remove the HDD
4. Install the SDD
5. Boot the Repair CD
6. Restore from the just created image

It took around 4 hours for the Image backup and about 2.5 hours for the restore.

After that it booted the SSD and was back where it had been with the HDD.

Boots and restarts are almost 10 times faster than with the HDD.

I installed the Samsung Magician software to confirm the firmware status and found no big issues in using it to pick an optimization strategy based on my priorities.

Note also that Windows 10 recognized the drive as being an SSD and the "Optimize Drive" tool now runs Trim instead of defragmenting the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are fine, except installing the Samsung Magician. This tool is not really needed and causes issue (applies wrong and useless tweaks, causes hibernation issues).